# Defensive copying and use of clone()

Tags: java

I'm still in the early days of learning java and really struggling to get to grips with defensive copying, interfaces, and immutability.

For background...I have created a class RegistrationNumber that is immutable, and uses an object factory (getInstance() method) to generate a random ID. FYI - I have another class called IdentificationNumber, which has a similar purpose, and approach (i.e. instantiation through an object factory, unique value), but the format of the ID differs.

A registration number, is associated with a person - there is 1/person and everyone's is unique. For this I have a Person interface, I then have an Abstract Class AbstractPerson which implements common behaviour, and two subclasses that extend AbstractPerson: Male and Female. That is unable to change.

When I instantiate a Person, I must associate them with a unique reference number. e.g.

```
AbstractPerson() {

            this.registration = RegistrationNumber.getInstance();

}
```

My getInstance() method is as follows (fyi - it still needs some consideration, I understand it's flawed, but I'm still in early stages):

```
   private static final Map<String, RegistrationNumber> REG = new HashMap<String, RegistrationNumber>();  

   public static final RegistrationNumber getInstance() {
   //allow for possibility of limit being reached.

   Random r = new Random();

   int numbers = r.nextInt(9000) + 1000;

   Character letter = (char)(r.nextInt(26) + 'a');

   String strRep = letter + "" + numbers;

   RegistrationNumber n = REG.get(strRep);

   if (n == null) {

       n = new RegistrationNumber(numbers, letter, strRep);

       REG.put(strRep, n);

    }

       return n;
    }
```

I must have an accessor method in my AbstractPerson class that returns the unique reference number, without allowing it to be modified.

I can't return a new object, because that will generate a new unique number, so I though I could just clone it using .clone() as follows:

```
 final RegistrationNumber getRegistration() {

    return (RegistrationNumber) registration.clone();

    }
```

But that's giving me an error....."clone has protected access in java.lang.Object"

Can I change the getInstance() method in the RegistrationNumber class so it takes a RegistrationNumber as a parameter and then when I call getRegistration() I can just check if that number exists and return it if it does? But what happens when I call getInstance() for the first time? How can it pass in a parameter of itself before it's been instantiated?!

This is for school, so please don't give code - just a nudge in the right direction, or clarification would help.

Help??!!

Comment: *I have created a class RegistrationNumber that is immutable*: then why would you ever clone it? What's the point? Nobody will ever modify it, since it's immutable.

Comment: Why can't you return `registration`?

Comment: And to add, you should always override function clone() in your class.

Comment: No help to your overall question, but ... `new RegistrationNumber(numbers, letter, strRep);` ... don't pass the strRep to the constructor, instead let the constructor `new RegistrationNumber(numbers, letter);` internally build the strRep (if it even needs to be pre-built)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you *want* is a method to create a `RegistrationNumber` from an existing `RegistrationNumber`.

You can make RegistrationNumber implement `Cloneable` for instance, and override the `clone()` method.

What I don't understand is why you think you *need* `AbstractPerson` to clone the RegistrationNumber when returning it.  If it's immutable, just return the actual object.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to tell for sure without seeing your full code, but the only two obvious mistakes you could have made here is to declare the registration object as an instance of Object like:

```
private Object registration;
```

In your AbstractPerson class. If that's the case, either change it to

```
private RegistrationNumber registration;
```

or downcast it before calling clone:

```
return (RegistrationNumber)(((RegistrationNumber)registration).clone());
```

OR you just haven't implemented clone at all in your RegistrationNumber class. In that case, ignore all the above and just implement it.

On a side note, it looks to me like you're using the singleton pattern to generate RegistrationNumbers. It's great to have a singleton generator so that it can save the numbers already generated like in your case, but getInstance() should be the method giving you the singleton instance, not the registration number. I suggest you discuss this idea with your teacher.